# Определение чисел

Tags: python

Функция должна  распознавать отрицательные числа и десятичные дроби, а так же распознаёт
десятичные дроби как с точкой, так и с запятой.
Пример:
-6,7 → Вы ввели отрицательное дробное число: -6.7
5 → Вы ввели положительное целое число: 5
5.4r → Вы ввели не корректное число: 5.4r
-.777 → Вы ввели отрицательное дробное число: -0.777

У меня получилось только так

```
def play():
    num = input("Введите число: ")
    if num.isdigit():
        num1 = int(num)
        if num1 > 0:
            print('Вы ввели положительное целое число: ', num1)
    elif not num.isdigit():
        print('Вы ввели не корректное число: ', num)


play()
while True:
    answer = input("Желаете продолжить? (Д/Н) ")
    if answer.upper() in ("Y", "Д"):
        play()
    elif answer.upper() in ("N", "Н"):
        print('Спасибо , возращайся)')
        break
```

Отрицательные числа не получается сделать (в принципе знаю по параметр isdigit с минусом не пропускает) и с дробями тоже самое . Помогите пожалуйста .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам дан мощный инструмент `try expect` и стандартные функции - используйте их:

```
text = "-5.2"
try:
    v = int(text)                                     # попробуем преобразовать строку в целое число
    print("ввели целое число:", v)
except:                                               # не получилось преобразовать строку в целое число
    try:
        v = float(text)                               # попробуем преобразовать строку в число с плавающей запятой
        print("ввели число с плавающей запятой:", v)
    except:                                           # не получилось преобразовать строку в число с плавающей запятой
        print("некорректное число")
```

Answer (score 0):

Легче всего это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений.
`\d+` для положительного целого,
`-\d+` для отрицательного целого,
`\d*[,.]\d+` для дробного положительного,
`-\d*[,.]\d+` для дробного отрицательного.

Проверить можно с помощью

```
import re
if re.fullmatch(r'\d+','12345'):
    print('это целое положительное')
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать, выложу что вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
import re
text = input('Введите число: ')
if text.isdigit():
    num1 = int(text)
    return 'Вы ввели положительное целое число:', num1
elif re.fullmatch(r'-\d+', text):
    return 'Вы ввели отрицательное целое число:', text
elif re.fullmatch(r'\d*[ ,.]\d+', text):
    return 'Вы ввели положительное дробное число:', text
elif re.fullmatch(r'-\d*[,.]\d+', text):
    return 'Вы ввели отрицательное дробное число:', text
elif not text.isdigit():
    return 'Вы ввели не корректное число:', text


while True:
    result = main()
    print(*result)
```

Примерно так , но 1 момент теперь остался как 0 приписать дроби
к примеру вводим .5 функция определяет что это дробь и печатает 0 (0.5)

Comment: Для дробных можно преобразовать в число с помощью float(text) и вывести

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
if text.isdigit():
    num1 = int(text)
    return 'Вы ввели положительное целое число:', num1
try:
    v = int(text)
    if v < 0:
        return 'Вы ввели отрицательное целое число:', v
except:
    list1 = list(text)
    i = ','
    if i in list1:
        new_n_name = '.'
        list1 = [a if a != i else new_n_name for a in list1]
    try:
        db = float(''.join(list1))
        if db > 0:
            return 'Вы ввели положительное дробное число:', db
        else:
            return 'Вы ввели отрицательное дробное число:', db
    except:
        return 'Вы ввели не корректное число:', text


while True:
    text = input('Введите число: ')
    if text.upper() in ("ВЫХОД", "E", "EXIT", "QUIT", "Q"):
        break
    result = main()
    print(*result)
```

Решил полностю без дополлнительных библиотек. с заменой запятой , может кому то понадобится